# Android SharedPreferences IOException

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am getting the following exception when committing a string to SharedPreferences. The exception is arbitrary and doesn't happen all the time. Has anyone encountered this issue anytime?

This is my code:

```
mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
long id= 358375;
SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSettings.edit();
e.putLong("some_key", id);
e.commit();
```

This is the exception:

```
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648): writeToFile: Got exception:
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648): java.io.IOException: java.nio.charset.CoderResult[Malformed-input error with erroneous input length 1]
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:225)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.endDocument(FastXmlSerializer.java:183)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:186)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:576)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:491)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:512)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
08-20 10:35:27.175: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(648):   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:434)
```

Comment: are these your exact value and key ?

Comment: No, the value is dynamically populated in the code. But its a plain string all the time.

Comment: i suggest you post an actual value that causes the crash.

Comment: Modified the question. It happened now even when saving a long value.

Comment: there may be something already in the sharedpref that causes the problem. I suggest you iterate on the content of the shared pref and log what is in it (and post it if nothing seems off)